# Why is it scipy.stats.gaussian_kde() slower than seaborn.kde_plot() for the same data?

Tags: python, scipy, distribution, seaborn, gaussian

In python 3.7, I have this numpy array with shape=(2, 34900). This arrays is a list of coordinates where the index 0 represents the X axis and the index 1 represents the y axis.

When I use seaborn.kde_plot() to make a visualization of the distribution of this data, I'm able to get the result in about 5-15 seconds when running on a i5 7th generation.

But when I try to run the following piece of code:

```
#Find the kernel for 
k = scipy.stats.kde.gaussian_kde(data, bw_method=.3)
#Define the grid
xi, yi = np.mgrid[0:1:2000*1j, 0:1:2000*1j]
#apply the function
zi = k(np.vstack([xi.flatten(), yi.flatten()]))
```

which finds the gaussian kernel for this data and applies it to a grid I defined, it takes much more time. I wasn't able to run the full array but when running on a slice with the size of 140, it takes about 40 seconds to complete.

The 140 sized slice does make an interesting result which I was able to visualize using `plt.pcolormesh()`.

My question is what I am missing here. If I understood what is happening correctly, I'm using the `scipy.stats.kde.gaussian_kde()` to create an estimation of a function defined by the data. Then I'm applying the function to a 2D space and getting it's Z component as result. Then I'm plotting the Z component. But how can this process be any different from 
`seaborn.kde_plot()` that makes the code take so much longer.

Scipy's implementation just goes through each point doing this:

```
for i in range(self.n):
    diff = self.dataset[:, i, newaxis] - points
    tdiff = dot(self.inv_cov, diff)
    energy = sum(diff*tdiff,axis=0) / 2.0
    result = result + exp(-energy)
```

Comment: Seaborn uses [bootstrapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics)) for most of its statistical functions.

Comment: Which part of that code is slow (line_profiler)? Did you check if seaborn is using scipy's or statmodel's algs internally (scipy seems to be fallback)? Check out seaborn's code too, it's open-source.

Comment: I was able to check Scipy's implementation, added to description, but it was quite hard to understand what was happening. There were MANY function call and conditional statements which made really hard to follow

Comment: So if @ImportanceOfBeingErnest is correct, seaborn just samples a bunch of data randomly from my data. Is that right? It would make sense since the visualizations done with it seemed not to fully represent the data.

Comment: I think my initial comment holds, but only because it's very general. While seaborn uses a lot of bootstrapping, it does not do so for kernel density estimation.

Comment: There are a lot of data points in this dataset. The fact that one could process it all faster than all this data could be read from disk indicates that it in fact only takes a sample and not the whole dataset.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It seems that seaborn just takes a sample of my data. Since the size is smaller, it is able to finish it in a small amount. On the other hand, SciPy uses every single point in its processing. So it takes way longer with the size of dataset I'm using.

Answer (score 11):

Seaborn has in general two ways to calculate the bivariate kde. If available, it uses `statsmodels`, if not, it falls back to `scipy`.

The scipy code is similar to what is shown in the question. It uses [`scipy.stats.gaussian_kde`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html#scipy.stats.gaussian_kde). The statsmodels code uses [`statsmodels.nonparametric.api.KDEMultivariate`](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.nonparametric.kernel_density.KDEMultivariate.html#statsmodels.nonparametric.kernel_density.KDEMultivariate).

However, for a fair comparisson we would need to take the same grid size for both methods. The standard gridsize for seaborn is 100 points.

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(42)
import seaborn.distributions as sd

N = 34900
x = np.random.randn(N)
y = np.random.randn(N)
bw="scott"
gridsize=100
cut=3
clip = [(-np.inf, np.inf), (-np.inf, np.inf)]

f = lambda x,y : sd._statsmodels_bivariate_kde(x, y, bw, gridsize, cut, clip)
g = lambda x,y : sd._scipy_bivariate_kde(x, y, bw, gridsize, cut, clip)
```

If we time those two functions,

```
# statsmodels
%timeit f(x,y)  # 1 loop, best of 3: 16.4 s per loop
# scipy
%timeit g(x,y)  # 1 loop, best of 3: 8.67 s per loop
```

Scipy is hence twice as fast as statsmodels (the seaborn default). The reason why the code in the question takes so long is that instead of a grid of size 100, a grid of size 2000 is used.

Seeing those results one would actually be tempted to use scipy instead of statsmodels. Unfortunately it does not allow to choose which one to use. One hence needs to manually set the respective flag.

```
import seaborn.distributions as sd
sd._has_statsmodels = False
# plot kdeplot with scipy.stats.kde.gaussian_kde
sns.kdeplot(x,y)
```